# Compare dates with mm/dd/yyyy gives opposite result

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compare two dates but always it gives me opposite result.

I am trying to compare below dates

```
var tocompare=09/22/2017 and var insurenceexpiry=04/02/2018
```

I tried to compare as below.

```
console.log(insurenceexpiry > tocompare);
console.log(insurenceexpiry < tocompare);
```

which gives me false and true. As per my knowledge *insurenceexpiry* is greater and when i compare as *insurenceexpiry > tocompare* it should give me true but I am getting false. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `tocompare=09/22/2017` You are deviding 9 by 22, and the result by 2017.

Comment: Are they dates or strings or numbers?? `console.log(insurenceexpiry, tocompare)`

Comment: Check out moment.js, it's a brilliant library for dealing with dates in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert it into dates using `new Date(datestring)`.

Otherwise `9/22/2017` without quotes will do math operations

```js
var tocompare=new Date("09/22/2017");
var insurenceexpiry=new Date("04/02/2018");

 console.log(insurenceexpiry > tocompare);
 console.log(insurenceexpiry < tocompare);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare 2 dates as string directly, then use `YYYY/MM/DD` format, (you can use any separator apart from `/`, the main thing is `YYYYMMDD`)

Otherwise parse them as date (as per [i--'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45839487/compare-dates-with-mm-dd-yyyy-gives-opposite-result/45839534#45839534)) and then compare, as a month or day can be bigger than another date, but that doesn't meant that it's actually a bigger date, so you cannot use `mmddyyyy` format for a simple string comparison to get which date is bigger.